# Inserting into a binary search tree in C

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference, heap-memory

I'm currently learning C and also some datastructures such as binary search trees etc. I have trouble understanding HOW exactly changing pointer values within a function works in some cases and in others doesn't... I'll attach some of my code I wrote. It's an insert function which inserts values in the correct places in the BST (it works as it should). I tried working with pointers to pointers to be able to change values withing a function. Even though it works, im still really confused why it actually does.
I don't quite understand why my insert function actually changes the BST even though I only work with local variables (tmp, parent_ptr) in my insert function and I don't really dereference any pointers apart from " tmp = *p2r " in the insert function.

Thanks for helping out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct TreeNode{
    int val;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
};

struct TreeNode** createTree(){
    struct TreeNode** p2r;
    p2r = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode*));
    *p2r = NULL;
    return p2r;
}

void insert(struct TreeNode** p2r, int val){
    // create TreeNode which we will insert
    struct TreeNode* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    new_node -> val = val;
    new_node -> left = NULL;
    new_node -> right = NULL;
    //define onestep delayed pointer
    struct TreeNode* parent_ptr = NULL;
    struct TreeNode* tmp = NULL;
    tmp = *p2r;
    // find right place to insert node
    while (tmp != NULL){
        parent_ptr = tmp;
        if (tmp -> val < val) tmp = tmp->right;
        else tmp = tmp->left;
    }
    if (parent_ptr == NULL){
        *p2r = new_node;
    }
    else if (parent_ptr->val < val){ //then insert on the right
        parent_ptr -> right = new_node;
    }else{
        parent_ptr -> left = new_node;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct TreeNode **p2r = createTree();
    insert(p2r, 4);
    insert(p2r, 2);
    insert(p2r, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it is indeed you who wrote the function then it is you who should explain us how it works.:)

Comment: It was mostly trial and errror and I don't find the code itself confusing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze the approach step by step.

At first we consider the following simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TreeNode{
    int val;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
};

void create( struct TreeNode *head, int val )
{
    head = malloc( sizeof( struct TreeNode ) );
    
    head->val   = val;
    head->left  = NULL;
    head->right = NULL;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct TreeNode *head = NULL;
    
    printf( "Before calling the function create head == NULL is %s\n",
            head == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
            
    create( head, 10 );
    
    printf( "After  calling the function create head == NULL is %s\n",
            head == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
            
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling the function create head == NULL is true
After  calling the function create head == NULL is true
```

As you can see the pointer `head` in main was not changed. The reason is that the function deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer `head`. So changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.

If you rename the function parameter to `head_parm` (to distinguish the original pointer named `head` and the function parameter) then you can imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
create( head, 10 );

//...

void create( /*struct TreeNode *head_parm, int val */ )
{
    struct TreNode *head_parm = head;
    int val = 10;
    head_parm = malloc( sizeof( struct TreeNode ) );
    //...
```

That is within the function there is created a local variable `head_parm` that is initialized by the value of the argument head and this function local variable `head_parm` is changed within the function.

It means that function arguments are passed by value.

To change the original pointer `head` declared in main you need to pass it by reference.

In C the mechanism of passing by reference is implemented by passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the pointer in a function you will get a direct access to the original object.

So let's rewrite the above program the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TreeNode{
    int val;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
};

void create( struct TreeNode **head, int val )
{
    *head = malloc( sizeof( struct TreeNode ) );
    
    ( *head )->val   = val;
    ( *head )->left  = NULL;
    ( *head )->right = NULL;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct TreeNode *head = NULL;
    
    printf( "Before calling the function create head == NULL is %s\n",
            head == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
            
    create( &head, 10 );
    
    printf( "After  calling the function create head == NULL is %s\n",
            head == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
            
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program output is

```
Before calling the function create head == NULL is true
After  calling the function create head == NULL is false
```

In your program in the question you did not declare the pointer to the head node like in the program above

```
struct TreeNode *head = NULL;
```

You allocated this pointer dynamically. In fact what you are doing in your program is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TreeNode{
    int val;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
};

void create( struct TreeNode **head, int val )
{
    *head = malloc( sizeof( struct TreeNode ) );
    
    ( *head )->val   = val;
    ( *head )->left  = NULL;
    ( *head )->right = NULL;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct TreeNode **p2r = malloc( sizeof( struct TreeNode * ) );
    *p2r = NULL;
    
    printf( "Before calling the function create *p2r == NULL is %s\n",
            *p2r == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
            
    create( p2r, 10 );
    
    printf( "After  calling the function create *p2r == NULL is %s\n",
            *p2r == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
            
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling the function create *p2r == NULL is true
After  calling the function create *p2r == NULL is false
```

That is compared with the previous program when you used the expression `&head` of the type `struct TreeNode **` to call the function `create` you are now introduced an intermediate variable `p2r` which stores the value of the expression `&head` due to this code snippet

```
struct TreeNode **p2r = malloc( sizeof( struct TreeNode * ) );
*p2r = NULL;
```

That is early you called the function create like

```
create( &head, 10 );
```

Now in fact you are calling the function like

```
struct TreeNode **p2r = &head; // where head was allocated dynamically
create( p2r, 10 );
```

The same takes place in your program. That is within the function insert dereferencing the pointer p2r you have a direct access to the pointer to the head node

```
if (parent_ptr == NULL){
    *p2r = new_node;
    ^^^^ 
}
```

As a result the function changes the pointer to the head node passed by reference through the pointer `p2r`.

The data members left and right of other nodes are also changed through references to them using the pointer `parent_ptr`

```
else if (parent_ptr->val < val){ //then insert on the right
    parent_ptr -> right = new_node;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
}else{
    parent_ptr -> left = new_node;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the thorough answer! So is my understanding correct that I need the ADDRESS of the root pointer in order to change it (the root) [That's what I need a pointer to a pointer for], but if I want to change any other part of the tree the root pointer is enough.. so I don't need to pass the pointer to the root if I want to change any value of the tree (other than the root itself) [I'd say that I can simply pass the root pointer to the function]? All of this of course when my root pointer is not a global variable and I want to change the things within a function..

Comment: @cactus_splines If you want to change the root pointer itself you need need to pass it by  reference  that is a pointer to the pointer. If you need to change a data member of a node then you need to pass a pointer to the node..

Answer (score 1):

While the pointers themselves are indeed local variables, they point to a specific location in memory. When you dereference the pointer by using the -> symbol, you're basically accessing the memory where that exact variable to which the pointer is pointing to is stored. This is why your changes are reflected outside the function as well.

You basically told a local variable where your tree is stored, it helped with the insertion, and then it went out of scope. The tree itself is not a local variable so the changes are reflected on it.

I suggest reading up on how pointers work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, always remember one thing about the pointers, **they store a memory address, rather than a value.** For example:

```
int val = 5;
int copy = val;
int *original = &val;

printf("%d\n", val);
printf("%d\n", copy);
printf("%d\n", *original);

val = 8;

printf("%d\n", val);
printf("%d\n", copy);
printf("%d\n", *original);
```

On executing this piece of code, the output will be

```
5
5
5
8
5
8
```

Notice, how on changing the value of **val**, the value of **copy** remains the same, and the value pointed the by original changes. This happens because the pointer **original** points to the memory location **val**.

Now, coming to the insert function, although you are only working with local variables(tmp, parent_ptr), but remember they are pointer variables, they refer to a memory address. So whenever within the loop, you traverse to **tmp -> right** or **tmp -> left**, you are actually jumping in memory from one location to another, in the correct order, that's why it works. The following example will make it more clear.

```
     56 (A)
     /    \
    /      \
  45 (B)  60 (C)
```

**Consider the above BST, with the memory address in brackets.  Let's insert 40 into this BST. Initially, tmp will point to A, address of 56. Now 40 is less than 56, so tmp goes to left and now points to B, address of 45. Once, again it goes to left and now it is null. But by now, parent_ptr points to B. So the new node for 40 gets attached to left of B.**

```
      56 (A)
     /    \
    /      \
  45 (B)  60 (C)
  /
 /
40 (D)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! As you say memory-address, you mean the address of the BST in the Heap (as my createTree function allocates memory in the Heap with "malloc" for the BST)? In my logic the local variable tmp is stored in the Stack but it points to the heap and that's why the BST is changed after the function is done? And just 1 more small question if you or anyone can answer: The "p2r" variable created in the createTree function is returned. Is this then saved on the Stack when I call the function createTree within the main function and assign it to a variable?

Comment: By memory address I mean, address of a node of a BST. Also, for the variable "p2r", when the createTree function returns, the address returned by the "p2r", is stored in the "p2r" variable in main, which resides on the function call Stack.